# Set hidden field value by Javascript

Tags: javascript, hidden-field, bootstrap-modal

How can I pass USER_ID of the tag `< a >` for a Javascript function Javascript that set a hidden field?

I tried the Javascript function `showConfirm()`, but the hidden field isn't being filled. It stays null... I think the onClick attribute, of the field `deleteid`, is wrote wrong.

I want fill this field by javascript. How can I?

The message of error says

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 1

probably because the hidden field `"id_action"` isn't receiving datas of the function.

Whatever, the main problem is set the function `showConfirm` by paramters `'show', $row['id']` for the hidden field `id_action`.

```
           <script>

            function showConfirm (action, delID) {
              if (action == 'show') {
                document.confirm.id_action.value = delID;
              }
            }
            </script>


             <tbody>
               <?php
                   if (!empty($_POST)) {
               if (isset($_POST['id_action'])) {
                $del_id   = $_POST['id_action'];
                    $delUser  = new User;
                    $delUser->deletarUsuario($del_id);
                    unset($delUser);
                }
            }
                 $listUser    = new User;
                 $result     = $listUser->listarUsers();
                 if (is_array($result)) {
                  foreach ($result as $row) {
                    echo "
                     <tr>
                       <td align='right'>" . $row['id'] . "</td>
                          <td>". $row['name'] . " ".$row['sobrename']."</td>
                          <td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>
                          <td>" . $row['login'] . "</td>
                          <td>
                              <a data-toggle='modal' id='deleteid' data-target='#modal_delUser' onclick=\"showConfirm('show'," . $row['id'] . ")\">
                              Remove
                              </a>
                          </td>
                     </tr>"; 
                  }
                } 
                unset($listUser);
              ?>
             </tbody>


                     <!-- Button trigger modal -->
              <div class='modal fade' id='modal_delUser' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='modal_delUserLabel' aria-hidden='true'>
              <div class='modal-dialog'>
                <div class='modal-content panel-danger'>
                  <div class='modal-header panel-heading'>
                    <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>
                    <h4 class='modal-title' id='modal_delUserLabel'>The user will be deleted</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class='modal-body'>
                    Are you sure continue?
                  </div>
                   <div class="modal-footer">
                    <form role="form" id="confirm" action="users.php" method="post">

                      <input type="hidden" name="id_action">  

                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Yes</button>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Here the SQL that I am generating from the query

```
public function deletarUsuario($id) {
    $del_id     = $this->db->real_escape_string(trim($id));
    if ($update = $this->db->query("DELETE FROM usuario WHERE id = $del_id")) {
        if ($this->db->affected_rows) {
            echo "<div><p>Deleted user!</p></div>";
        }
        else {
            echo "<div><p>Failed to delete user.</p></div>";
        }

    }
    else {
        echo "<div><p>". $this->db->error."</p></div>";
                echo "<script>$('#modal_erroBD').modal('show');</script>";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it in php by using `$id_action = $_POST["id_action"]`

Check if you are passing the id at this stage:

change

```
             if (isset($_POST['id_action'])) {
                $del_id   = $_POST['id_action'];
                    $delUser  = new User;
                    $delUser->deletarUsuario($del_id);
                    unset($delUser);
             }
```

to

```
             if (isset($_POST['id_action'])) {
                $del_id   = $_POST['id_action'];
                    echo $del_id;
             }
```

Comment: Show us the SQL that you are generating from the query as it is not in the code above.

Comment: No problem. I edited the post to show you how to check if you are passing the user id in `$del_id`.  The user id should be displayed, if not then the problem may be here `<input type="hidden" name="id_action">`. How are you populating this field in the form?

Comment: I filled this field by the parameters of the function `showConfirm`, but  I think that this function was wrote wrong. 

So, the SQL works fine. If I try fill a value, like number 9 of row the usuario's table, in field `id_action`, then, the row 9 is deleted.

Oh, and the user id is not displayed through echo command.

Comment: Then as I suspected, the php is ok - You need to understand how the hidden field `id_action` is being populated as it is not working.

Comment: Truly, I think it's the onClick attribute, of the field `deleteid`, wich is wrote wrong.

Comment: I found the issue! There was a wrong concatenation in onClick event of the hidden field `deleteid`. When I replace the symbol `.` for a symbol `+`, the id was be displayed. But, the rest of table's rows - like name, login and email - got away! ):